# Can't move shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have created new project and placed new rectangle in it. I'm trying to move rectangle using direct selection and path selection tools, but it don't moves. When I try to move using Move Tool - it moves whole page together with rectangle, but I need to move only rectangle. Layer is not locked. How to use move tool in Photoshop?

UPD: layers panel:

[image]

Comment: Do us a favor, make a print-screen of your layer panel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, now that you have added a layers panel I MUST say that this is NOT illustrator, it's nothing like it when it comes to layers and objects editability, in illustrator you can have multiple objects inside a layer and still move them individually.

In photoshop, you can't **(see note below)** move each object individually once you draw them inside the same layer...they are merged together. In order to move each object individually, like you would do in AI, you need to have each of them in a separate layer.

*Note:
When I say that you can't, I mean not as easy and "normal" like in illustrator. In your image for example, in order to move the rectangle, you have to select the Rectangular Marquee Tool, select the rectangle with precision from one corner to another, select the Move Tool, click and drag. Though this will also leave an empty space where your rectangle used to be.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue is too simple and I didn't understand but...:

You need to use an individual layer for that rectangle. Your rectangle is on the same layer as your white background. Draw that rectangle on a new separate layer.

You can add layers by clicking the little icon at the bottom of that layer window. You can use as many as you want to make it easier for you to manipulate each element you draw.

You can move the rectangle *but after* selecting it; it's a 2-steps process. If it's on its own layer, then you can simply move it individually (in 1 step). The "move tool" works when you select the shape first and then use the move tool. But frankly, it's often easier to simply draw the shape on a separate layer; this way you won't need to select it every time and you can move it freely.

[image: Photoshop layers]

---

**Here's a basic tutorial about layers! It's really a good starting point to know about layers and I'm certain you'll love using them! I also recommend you to have a look at other beginner's tutorials.**

http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/layers-intro/

http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/essential-layers-panel-preferences/